# Enable Unsolicited response in Sierra Aircard 320U

Tags: serial-port, at-command, modem, lte, dongle

I have AirCard 320u from Sierra wireless.It will expose 4 serial ports ttyUSB0,ttyUSB1,ttyUSB3,ttyUSB4

I am trying to get unsolicited response from the modem (AT port ttyUSB2).
 I have tried AT^CURC=1 ,But this AT command is not supported by Sierra dongle.

(Same command is working in Huawei dongles)

I want to get different unsolicit responses like 
^BOOT
^RSSI
^MODE
^DSFLOWRPT
^CONN
^CEND
^CONF
^ORIG
Please suggest if any other method is there to enable these responses

Comment: AT!SWICALLPROG does something similar, I believe.

Comment: I tried that ,But got response as "NOT IMPLEMENTED" :(